# Isuzu D-max 3.0 2009 port OBDII

Tags: chevrolet, obd-ii, diesel, isuzu, pick-up

I'm not a mechanic or anything, but I'm too curious.
I live in Colombia and I have a vehicle that is marketed here as Chevrolet Isuzu D-max 3.0 model 2009 (diesel engine)

[image: Chevrolet Isuzu D-max 3.0 model 2009 (diesel engine)]

I know that my vehicle has an OBDII port, but I need your help to identify a scanner that is compatible with my vehicle, in a website I found that it works with the 11bit CAN protocol 500kb. [here url](https://www.outilsobdfacile.com/vehicle-list-compatible-obd2/isuzu)
**It is right?**

I have seen different products on ebay, but apparently in the US this vehicle is not marketed and I can not find a product that specifies that it works

[Can this product work for my vehicle?](https://www.ebay.com/itm/US-ELM327-Bluetooth-ODB2-OBDII-Car-Diagnostic-Scanner-Code-Reader-Detector-Auto/112871406201?hash=item1a47a8fa79:rk:5:pf:0&checksum=112871406201699f4dd219db4da89121170e81c2f52a&enc=AQADAAADAFjVrDbVsZ8oH%2F8PNHtt9VX4%2Fw7FZcmMuqsX8uaFEduV6nK5366hbLR%2FrUJ4jEBXTYwLl04gU8ZNfgYX8pT8uHBik2E750i1kmgV34tX3B8Gop0m91ST4JoHfdApnXPQ%2BJPe8WFNQmrSUsd1Es6l%2BMx8EvhUDD6F7AyTeQGumDg%2F5PjCLd7X6%2BwRx1Ux7p7ihDQJwLwWhG767fCHZH5ypQ3t2SJWF9vedDNsbJgn33KIzvLxYRGaiX4TyFJtXLhqq98sUmBymyXjMMDAQPSCpzg7XjuJWXbQ4083WXExqkorFCHFBf2EJ%2BubC8%2Bk7sBgT%2FqWYRIvww%2BpVFKfggCV4rFrgEp4UjlUYd3838GtSt2uXrzgHq69%2Bax4nu%2BNm41vu9TWqLi%2BY6dj2yiRbfKH7gL5PpmkacHTtOylHDjb1J8eOUNOpPZ02Rvf4lMG4BSw0FWNTl2RRRjBKlxntWFkbDlw8JUdjufQUxLa6MkSSoFYxBaRcmqnB5RBjtDEYCFJkk4PV75VkrUMuvjbvbWS1pFAYxGorQvKNi72AdN%2Bjky9llhAgpKgJAdXO0d%2BKPHruhcZNxy3zcCbad2ERRjVqW0W0zPue9esrI0X6P%2FaH2ITNTyoTMXdQ8xvrM94XpGZ3K7Kn8No2ieJe4FvsgNcENxPwypl%2BUA7wT%2FaDuV9u%2FmnxPERJbpqHygMCrYezlF62P%2FsNoMBN5MszPlujeUR9h4DlzBm3FDs%2FP%2FvLfjPohyn7Zlw3YOjI6EobBAPhYx7LdOeMPZ%2FHWIMPjjLZmiHXc8uDCyn8E1ssB32i587UcyHN2IETfg7eW6XMCPxSrJTxt7cGpkTxqj0%2B%2Bi7OFHG1zGArfTHcVZ1unyK1WkNrqJ7iSDlOCIhjk2MVVbXi0nn2xGieKkwhrfZgr0eYTsZ0mY3mPDxAn%2B9pBT10xAxgCN%2B6daSbju2CuHo6c6U1voO1QNh%2Bq1ephARjD7soK9a2ldnSfpWLKFJJUWSyxcsiMb9j2GAVH5iQLYYG3F8NnUvdQ%3D%3D)

Thank you very much for your comments and suggestions

Answer (score 1):

The whole point with the OBDII standard is that **any** standards compliant OBDII reader should be able to read your codes. Now, that's not necessarily all codes as some manufacturers have proprietary readers to access some diagnostics, but you probably can't get one of those and even if you could they cost stupid money so out of reach for the curious.

So it's not about compatibility as much as features. If all you want is to read your codes every once and awhile then the cheapest possible option is a bluetooth OBD reader which will sync to a free app on your phone or tablet. I use one of these myself with Torque Lite and I have no complaints. There are also self-contained units with LCD screens which go from basic functionality up to advanced functions. So buy a reader based on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

**An ELM327 device should work for any OBDII vehicle found on the road here in the US**. They are very universal.

You'll need to ensure you are getting the right reader for your *monitoring device* though. There are specific ones for iOS and Android devices. The Bluetooth ones will not work with Apple products. You need one which works on WiFi. The ELM327 devices I've see usually state what they work with, so ensure you check. Whenever you get your device, don't leave it plugged in, as the ones I've seen are "always on" even with the vehicle shut off. So it will drain your battery over time. Also, Torque Lite is a free app which works well on Android devices (not sure what's good for iOS).